# Kotlin - get the non-nullable inference of a nullable generic type inference

Tags: kotlin

I want to know whether it's possible to force kotlin to infer the non-nullable of a given type inference. Consider the following example:

```
abstract class Wrapper<T>
class StringWrapper : Wrapper<String>()

fun <O, P> wrap(property: KProperty1<O, P>, wrapper: Wrapper<P>) {

}
```

When I call `wrap` on a non-nullable property, everything works fine:

```
data class NonNullableExample(val value: String)
wrap(NonNullableExample::value, StringWrapper())
```

But when I call `wrap` on a nullable property, I get a compiler error, because the inference of `P` is nullable, whereas `StringWrapper` isn't:

```
data class NullableExample(val value: String?)
wrap(NullableExample::value, StringWrapper())
```

> Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter `P` in
>
> `fun <O, P> wrap(property: KProperty1<O, P>, wrapper: Wrapper<P>): Unit`
>
> None of the following substitutions
>
> `(KProperty1<NullableExample, String>, Wrapper<String>)`
>
> `(KProperty1<NullableExample, String?>, Wrapper<String?>)`
>
> can be applied to
>
> `(KProperty1<NullableExample, String?>, StringWrapper)`

So basically what I want is, regardless of `P` being nullable or non-nullable, `P` of `Wrapper<P>` should always be the non-nullable form of `P`. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you define a derived property from `value` but is non-nullable, and do `NullableExample::NonNullableValue` when calling `wrap`? Of course you'll need to deal with what happens when `value` is `null`, but you'll need to deal with that somewhere anyway, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So basically what I want is, regardless of `P` being nullable or non-nullable, `P` of `Wrapper<P>` should always be the non-nullable form of `P`.

That doesn't quite make sense as stated: there is just one `P`, not a separate one in `Wrapper<P>` and `KProperty1<O, P>`. So if you want them to be different, you can't use `P` for both.

But `KProperty1` is covariant in the result type, so a `KProperty1<O, P>` is also a `KProperty1<O, P?>`. So if you change the signature to

```
fun <O, P : Any> wrap(property: KProperty1<O, P?>, wrapper: Wrapper<P>): Unit
```

it will accept both nullable and non-nullable properties:

```
wrap(NonNullableExample::value, StringWrapper())
wrap(NullableExample::value, StringWrapper())
// both compile
```